# How do I blur a background image without blurring the other elements? (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to blur a background image on my website without blurring all of the other elements. I've been trying all morning and I'm burnt out. Can anyone help?

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQPPs.png)
[This is what I want the background to look like, but the text should not be blurred.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGLxx.png)

This is what my code is looking like

```
        <section id="upper" style="background-image: url(images/Icon\ Grid\ \(1\).svg); filter: blur(4px); ">
            <p style="visibility: hidden;">top</p> 
            <h1>Practice Site</h1>
            <p style="font-size: 23px; margin-top: -25px; position:relative;">HTML & CSS.</p>
            <hr style="width: 100%; margin-top: 500px; border-radius: 5px; color: lightblue;">
        </section>
```

Comment: move `h1` and `p` out of `section` tag. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp